# Coordinate transformations from a randomly generated normal vector

Tags: python, 3d, coordinate-transformation, rotational-matrices

I'm trying to randomly generate coordinate transformations for a fitting routine I'm writing in python. I want to rotate my data (a bunch of [x,y,z] coordinates) about the origin, ideally using a bunch of randomly generated normal vectors I've already created to define planes -- I just want to shift each plane I've defined so that it lies in the z=0 plane.

Here's a snippet of my code that should take care of things once I have my transformation matrix. I'm just not sure how to get my transformation matrix from my normal vector and if I need something more complicated than numpy for this.

```
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np
import math

origin = np.array([35,35,35])
normal = np.array([np.random.uniform(-1,1),np.random.uniform(-1,1),np.random.uniform(0,1)])
mag = np.sum(np.multiply(normal,normal))
normal = normal/mag

a = normal[0]
b = normal[1]
c = normal[2]

#I know this is not the right transformation matrix but I'm not sure what is...
#Looking for the steps that will take me from the normal vector to this transformation matrix
rotation = np.array([[a, 0, 0], [0, b, 0], [0, 0, c]])

#Here v would be a datapoint I'm trying to shift?
v=(test_x,test_y,test_z)
s = np.subtract(v,origin) #shift points in the plane so that the center of rotation is at the origin
so = np.multiply(rotation,s) #apply the rotation about the origin
vo = np.add(so,origin) #shift again so the origin goes back to the desired center of rotation

x_new = vo[0]
y_new = vo[1]
z_new = vo[2]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,9))
plt3d = fig.gca(projection='3d')
plt3d.scatter(x_new, y_new, z_new, s=50, c='g', edgecolor='none')
```

Comment: What is your question? Is the current code working or not? Thanks.

Comment: My question is how do I get the right transformation matrix from the normal vector?

Comment: Now I understand your question. Several transformation matrices could give you the right answer, because you can rotate your plane around the z-axis. Perhaps try http://math.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the people over in the math stack exchange, I have an answer that works. But note that it would not work if you also needed to perform a translation, which I didn't because I'm defining my planes by a normal vector and a point, and the normal vector changes but the point does not. Here's what worked for me.

```
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np
import math

def unit_vector(vector):
    """ Returns the unit vector of the vector.  """
    return vector / np.linalg.norm(vector)

cen_x, cen_y, cen_z = 35.112, 35.112, 35.112
origin = np.array([[cen_x,cen_y,cen_z]])

z_plane_norm = np.array([1,1,0])
z_plane_norm = unit_vector(z_plane_norm)

normal = np.array([np.random.uniform(-1,1),np.random.uniform(-1,1),np.random.uniform(0,1)])
normal = unit_vector(normal)

a1 = normal[0]
b1 = normal[1]
c1 = normal[2]

rot = np.matrix([[b1/math.sqrt(a1**2+b1**2), -1*a1/math.sqrt(a1**2+b1**2), 0], [a1*c1/math.sqrt(a1**2+b1**2), b1*c1/math.sqrt(a1**2+b1**2), -1*math.sqrt(a1**2+b1**2)], [a1, b1, c1]])

init = np.matrix(normal)

fin = rot*init.T
fin = np.array(fin)

# equation for a plane is a*x+b*y+c*z+d=0 where [a,b,c] is the normal
# so calculate d from the normal
d1 = -origin.dot(normal)

# create x,y
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(cen_x-0.5,cen_x+0.5,0.05),np.arange(cen_y-0.5,cen_y+0.5,0.05))

# calculate corresponding z
z1 = (-a1 * xx - b1 * yy - d1) * 1./c1

#-------------

a2 = fin[0][0]
b2 = fin[1][0]
c2 = fin[2][0]

d2 = -origin.dot(fin)
d2 = np.array(d2)
d2 = d2[0][0]

z2 = (-a2 * xx - b2 * yy - d2) * 1./c2

#-------------

# plot the surface
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,9))
plt3d = fig.gca(projection='3d')

plt3d.plot_surface(xx, yy, z1, color='r', alpha=0.5, label = "original")   
plt3d.plot_surface(xx, yy, z2, color='b', alpha=0.5, label = "rotated")  


plt3d.set_xlabel('X (Mpc)')
plt3d.set_ylabel('Y (Mpc)')
plt3d.set_zlabel('Z (Mpc)')

plt.show()
```

If you do need to perform a translation as well, see the full answer I worked off of [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956699/getting-a-transformation-matrix-from-a-normal-vector).

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a wrong concept of rotation matrices. Rotation matrices define rotation of a certain angle and can not have diagonal structure.

If you imagine every rotation as a composition of a rotation around the X axis, then around the Y axis, then around the Z axis, you can build each matrix and compose the final rotation as product of matrices

```
R = Rz*Ry*Rx
Rotated_item = R*original_item
```

or

```
Rotated_item = np.multiply(R,original_item)
```

In this formula Rx is the first applied rotation. 

Be aware that

- you can obtain your rotation by composing many different set of 3 rotation
- the sequence it is not fixed, it could be X-Y-Z or Z-Y-X or Z-X-Z or whatever combination. The values of angles may change as the sequence changes
- it is "dangerous" use this matrices for rotation of critical values (90-180-270-360 degrees)

How to compose each single rotation matrix around 1 axis? See [this image from wikipedia](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/a6821937d5031de282a190f75312353c970aa2df). Numpy has all things you need.

Now you just have to define 3 angles values.
Of course you can derive 3 angles values from a random normalized vector (a,b,c) as you write in your question, but rotation is a process that transform a vector in another vector. Maybe you have to specify something like
*"I want to find the rotation R around the origin that transform (0,0,1) into (a,b,c)".* A completely different rotation R' is the one that transform (1,0,0) into (a,b,c).